# Best way to handle responses in onMessage()

Tags: java, activemq-classic, ibm-mq, message-queue, mq

I have stand alone MQ listener which listens to the queue. What is the best way to handle the responses in the onMessage(). I dont want my business logic to be there in the onMessage(). Also I dont want the onMessage() to wait for the parsing the response and storing in the DB.

```
public abstract class MQReceiver implements MessageListener{
    public void pollResults(Long counter) throws JMSException, InterruptedException {
        Queue rQueue = null;
        QueueSession session = null;
        QueueReceiver receiver;
        count = counter;        

        try{
            session =   connection.createQueueSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
            rQueue = session.createQueue(getReceiveQueue());

            receiver = session.createReceiver(rQueue);
            receiver.setMessageListener(this);
            connection.start();
            while(count > 0){
                logger.info("Waiting......Count >> " + count);
                Thread.sleep(SLEEPTIME);    
            }

            if(count == 0){
                session.close();
                logger.info("exiting poll results");
            }

        }finally{
            if(session != null)
                session.close();
        }

      }

@Override
    public void onMessage(Message message) {
             if (message instanceof TextMessage) {
                //Parse and Apply business logic
                //Store in DB
             }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to wait for the business logic and DB interaction then you could offwork to another thread and return.

But be informed that if you offwork to another thread, you lose your exception control over it.

I think you can start with `CompletableFuture` in java 8:

```
        YourOffworkService service;
        ....
        public void onMessage(Message msg){
           if (message instance of TextMessage) {
             CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> { service.process(msg);});
           } 
        }
```

**Edit**

In java 7 you can done by `Thread` or `Runnable`

```
public class YourOffworkService extends Thread {
      private Message message;

      public YourOffworkService(Message message) {
       this.message = message;
      }

      public void run() {

       // Here come the business logic / DB interaction
      }
}
```

Then in your `onMessage()`:

```
public void onMessage(Message msg) {
    ...bla bla...
    new YourOffworkService(msg).start();
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I'm using Java 7. Could you suggest me the best option in Java 7.

Comment: I tried doing that using ThreadPoolTaskExecutor, I'm using spring batch and in the writer it is calling a Message listener class. The problem is the underlying Table is been locked by another spring batch running parallel and vice versa which affects the onMessage (). It is not sending the acknowledgment back.

Comment: Once you submit to your thread pool using `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor.submit()`, you got a `Future`back. Use that `Future` to check

Comment: Then use the alternative `submit()` method then. When you use `execute`, you completely handover your control to the executor

Answer (score 0):

But why don't you want the OnMessage thread wait for you to complete your work? It's pretty much the purpose of the messaging system. If you fail to insert into DB because of some error, the message will be rolled back and is not lost - and a second try can be attempted. If you off-load the logic/database operation elsewhere you loose fault tolerance.

Anyway, the best way is not to spawn threads or similar from OnMessage, but to enqueue the message to some internal queue, which you read by worker-threads. If you simply spin up threads, you will have a problem handling say a few thousand messages on the queue at startup. Java has a nice [BlockingQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) for this purpose. That way you can control how many threads should be busy doing logic/database stuff. You need somewhere to put a limit how many message you can read from ActiveMQ before you need to wait until the backend can keep up. A queue is a nice way to do that.

Example with blocking queue.

```
final BlockingQueue<String> internalQueue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<String>(CAPACITY);

...

new Thread(new Runnable() { // TODO make a named class and schedule as many thread as needed.
        @Override public void run() {
            try {
                while (true) {
                    String msg = internalQueue.take();
                    System.out.println(msg);
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println("Interrupted.");
            }
        }
    }).start();

...

public void onMessage(Message message) {
         if (message instanceof TextMessage) {
              internalQueue.put(((TextMessage)message).getText());
         }
}
```

Anyway, when you think about it another time, then isn't it better to just keep the queue in ActiveMQ anyway? If the process is too time consuming, consider breaking the flow up into multiple steps with queues in between.

Example:

- *queue* -> validate/error check -> *queue* -> massive logic -> *queue* -> heavy database persistence -> queue -> *notifications*